# Cropping a background image through CSS

Tags: css, themes, media-queries, background-image, crop

So, as a newbie I'm just getting lost in what I'm trying to do:
On the webshop I need to set up for my work, we are working with a 3rd party template for Lightspeed (e-commerce platform). In this theme, we've got 3 "highlight" items. These are background images + overlapping text and button to display products.

I've set the minimum height for these ID's to 800px:

```
#highlight-1,#highlight-2,#highlight-3 {
   min-height: 800px;
}
```

So far so good, everything works.
But now, on a mobile platform (yeah, you can laugh already if you want because you know whats coming don't ya?), you've guessed it: the images are WAY too big.

I would love to crop the image to (maybe about) half the size for mobile platforms in portrait mode, so the essence of the image is still retained and users don't have to swipe about a kilometer before they reach the end of the page.

The only thing I can find within the .rain and .css files I have access to is:

```
#highlight-1{ background: url('highlight_1_image.jpg') no-repeat;}
#highlight-2{ background: url('highlight_2_image.jpg') no-repeat;}
#highlight-3{ background: url('highlight_3_image.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

I can edit this ánd I have access to a custom .css editor for the template

Anyone who can help a newbie out? Thanks a bunch in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution is to use a media query to serve a smaller image. This cuts down on bandwidth for mobile visitors who may be using limited data, and I believe has an impact on your page ranking within Google and the like.

```
#highlight-1{ background: url('highlight_1_image.jpg') no-repeat;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #highlight-1{ background: url('highlight_1_mobile_image.jpg') no-repeat;}
}
```

If that's not an option, you can explicitly specify size with the `background-size` property, or set it to `cover` (scaled up or down so a single instance of the image will completley cover the element with cropping if required) or `contain` (scaled up or down so that the element is completley filled horizontally **or** vertically)

Comment: I never even thought about serving a smaller image. That's a great idea! The only thing is..will that overwrite (or ignore) the min-height of 800px I have for the #highlight-#? And will it overwrite/replace the other background image, or do I need to use some kind of !important tag? 
Never really worked with media queries myself, so this is kind of a new area for me.

Comment: Media queries by themselves do not apply any styles, so no need to worry about your `min-height: 800px`. Think of media queries as sectioned off parts of your stylesheet - the rules within them only get applied if your visitor meets the conditions specified in the media query. `!important` is only required if you try and use a weaker selector in your media query. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/media-queries/info

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your additional explanation and reading material, you're a great help! Unfortunately, I can't change anything right now, but I'll post an update tomorrow.

Thanks again! :)

Comment: So i've followed up on your advice and the loading in of the mobile images is the perfect solution! The only problem I'm having right now, is still the min-height: 800px that still scaling and dominating the images. Any way I can remove that just for mobile users?

Comment: Aye, within the media query, `min-height: 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Doesn't work though I'm afraid.. 
`@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #highlight-1{ 
 background:url('//static.webshopapp.com/shops/249018/files/158718656/test1.jpg') no-repeat;
      min-height: 0; !important
  }`

When I check it in chrome with inspect element, it sees the `min-height: 0` like you described, but it is crossed out and the min-height: 800px; overrules it so it seems...

Comment: Move the `!important` to before the semi-colon, like `...; min-height: 0 !important;`

Comment: And there you go, that fixed it! How silly of me, sorry about that!
Thank you for all your help. You're an absolute life saver <3